# How to match on prefix in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

let's say that in my elasticsearch index I have a field called "dots" which will contain a string of punctuation separated words (e.g. "first.second.third").

I need to search for e.g. "first.second" and then get all entries whose "dots" field contains a string being exactly "first.second" or starting with "first.second.".

I have a problem understanding how the text querying works, at least I have not been able to create a query which does the job.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Elasticsearch has [Path Hierarchy Tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) that was created exactly for such use case. Here is an example of how to set it for your index:

```
# Create a new index with custom path_hierarchy analyzer 
# See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/prefix-test" -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "prefix-test-analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "prefix-test-tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "prefix-test-tokenizer": {
                    "type": "path_hierarchy",
                    "delimiter": "."
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "dots": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "prefix-test-analyzer",
                    //"index_analyzer": "prefix-test-analyzer", //deprecated
                    "search_analyzer": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
# Put some test data
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/prefix-test/doc/1" -d '{"dots": "first.second.third"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/prefix-test/doc/2" -d '{"dots": "first.second.foo-bar"}'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/prefix-test/doc/3" -d '{"dots": "first.baz.something"}'
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/prefix-test/_refresh"
echo
# Test searches. 
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/prefix-test/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "dots": "first"
        }
    }
}'
echo
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/prefix-test/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "dots": "first.second"
        }
    }
}'
echo
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/prefix-test/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "dots": "first.second.foo-bar"
        }
    }
}'
echo
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/prefix-test/doc/_search?pretty=true&q=dots:first.second"
echo
```

Comment: Sorry, did not see your post until now!! Thanks a lot :) Will look into it as soon as I get the time!

Comment: How do I perform the settings and mappings stuff in my Java code?

Comment: `client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("test").addMapping("type1", mapping).setSettings(settings).execute().actionGet();`

Comment: Say you also had a document '{"dots": "first.second.third.fourth"}', how would you get only the documents at the "first.second" level, i.e. ["first.second.third", "first.second.foo-bar"]?  In essence, I want to get all the documents in the "first.second" module, and don't want to get the children beneath them because there's a lot, ostensibly.

Comment: Example doesn't work on current ES version. Needs update.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a much easier way, as pointed out in elasticsearch [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-text-query.html#_text_phrase_prefix):

just use:

```
{
    "text_phrase_prefix" : {
        "fieldname" : "yourprefix"
    }
}
```

or since 0.19.9:

```
{
    "match_phrase_prefix" : {
        "fieldname" : "yourprefix"
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
{   
    "prefix" : { 
        "fieldname" : "yourprefix" 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [prefix queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/prefix-query.html).

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "prefix" : { "dots" : "first.second" }
    }
}'
```

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/3457388) works on a new index. Do you have a special mapping on your index? Maybe you should try on a new, clean index.

Comment: Is there any efficiency difference between using prefix search or path hierarchy tokenizer?

Comment: @JaySullivan ``prefix`` query is term query, so there is no analyze => so much faster. But no analyze.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a commodin chars to make your query, something like this:

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/myapp/index -d '{
    "dots": "first.second*"
}'
```

more examples about the syntax at: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html

Comment: The JSON you posted isn't actually a query, can you correct it?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar solution - but matching only a prefix. I found @imtov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127065/3508719) to get me almost there, but for one change - switching the analyzers around:

```
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "dots": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "keyword",
                "search_analyzer": "prefix-test-analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

instead of

```
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "dots": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "prefix-test-analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way adding:

```
'{"dots": "first.second"}'
'{"dots": "first.third"}'
```

Will add only these full tokens, without storing `first`, `second`, `third` tokens.

Yet searching for either

```
first.second.anyotherstring
first.second
```

will correctly return only the first entry:

```
'{"dots": "first.second"}'
```

Not exactly what you asked for but somehow related, so I thought could help someone.