# elasticsearch: How to rank first appearing words or phrases higher

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

For example, if I have the following documents:

```
1. Casa Road
2. Jalan Casa
```

Say my query term is "cas"... on searching, both documents have same scores. I want the one with `casa` appearing earlier (i.e. document 1 here) and to rank first in my query output.

I am using an edgeNGram Analyzer. Also I am using aggregations so I cannot use the normal sorting that happens after querying.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html) to boost the items that start with the search query:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "match" : { "name" : "cas" }
        },
        "should": {
            "prefix" : { "name" : "cas" }
        },
    }
}
```

I'm assuming the values you gave is in the `name` field, and that that field is not analyzed. If it is analyzed, maybe look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127065/6681) for more ideas.

The way it works is:

1. Both documents will match the query in the `must` clause, and will receive the same score for that. A document won't be *included* if it doesn't match the `must` query.
2. Only the document with the term starting with `cas` will match the query in the `should` clause, causing it to receive a higher score. A document won't be *excluded* if it doesn't match the `should` query.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit more involved, but it should work.
Basically, you need the position of the term within the text itself and, also, the number of terms from the text. The actual scoring is computed using scripts, so you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in `elasticsearch.yml` config file:

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
```

This is what you need:

- a mapping that is using `term_vector` set to `with_positions`, and `edgeNGram` and a sub-field of type `token_count`:

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "term_vector": "with_positions",
          "index_analyzer": "edgengram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "word_count": {
              "type": "token_count",
              "store": "yes",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "name_ngrams": {
          "min_gram": "2",
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "max_gram": "30"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "edgengram_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "name_ngrams"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- test documents:

```
POST /test/test/1
{"text":"Casa Road"}
POST /test/test/2
{"text":"Jalan Casa"}
```

- the query itself:

```
GET /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "text": {
                  "value": "cas"
                }
              }
            },
            "script_score": {
              "script": "termInfo=_index['text'].get('cas',_POSITIONS);wordCount=doc['text.word_count'].value;if (termInfo) {for(pos in termInfo){return (wordCount-pos.position)/wordCount}};"
            },
            "boost_mode": "sum"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- and the results:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1.3715843,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.3715843,
            "_source": {
               "text": "Casa Road"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.8715843,
            "_source": {
               "text": "Jalan Casa"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```