# Bucketize the billion records on the basis of frequently changing prefixes(~200,000) in an optimized way

Tags: database, elasticsearch, matching, elasticsearch-aggregation

Suppose I have 10 millions of records getting generated on a daily basis with the schema -

```
Day(type - date)

Key Column(type - String)
Ex -  a_b_c_1_2 (parts separated by `_`)

Value(type - decimal) 
Ex - 11.25
```

**Key Column** - This column has some static part and some dynamic/random part.

Now I have a best guess algorithm, taking a sufficient amount of time, to automatically identify the prefix/static part from the key column. 
Ex - a_b_c_ for key **a_b_c_1_2**

Also, these prefixes can change frequently on the basis of user feedback.
Ex - A user can come and say **a_b_** or **a_b_c_1_** is the valid prefix instead of **a_b_c_**.

Total prefixes are going to be in the range of 100K - 200K.

**Now, my use case requires to figure out the total value generated by these prefixes for a given time-frame(date-1 to date-2)**.

One option is to store the aggregated value for each prefix on a daily basis in a relational DB but I don't want to iterate over a whole year's data again to identify the aggregated value for the updated prefixes.

I explored Elastic search as one of the option to dynamically get the summation of value based on a given prefix.

Reference - [How to match on prefix in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117275/how-to-match-on-prefix-in-elasticsearch/12127065#12127065)

But the above solution will not be efficient for 200k prefixes as I have to query ES for each prefix one by one, which will be time consuming if someone asks for prefix values for the last one year.

**Is there any other mechanism to optimize the solution using ES, maybe some kind of JOIN between prefixes and raw data to get the aggregated value for each prefix for a given time frame?**

**Any other indexed based database which can be helpful to solve this use case efficiently?**